# ruby on railsで"オブジェクトでサポートされていないプロパティまたはメソッドです"が出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby初心者です。
以下のエラーが解決できなくて困っております。
↓コマンド上に表示されている文

> ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: オブジェクトでサポートされていないプロパティまたはメソッドです。):

```
4:     <title>RailsApp2</title>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6:
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turboli
nks-track': 'reload' %>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'r
eload' %>
9:   </head>
10:
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ブラウザ上では画像の様なエラーがでています。
先日、エラーがどうしても解決できなくて新しくアプリを生成して作り直していたのですが、前は出ていなかったエラーがでてしまい、ググっても解決法が分かりませんでした。どなたかわかる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `C:/Users/...` とあるのでWindows環境ですね。日本語化されたエラーメッセージを出しているのはWindows上のJavaScriptエンジンですね。ランタイムエンジンは何ですか? (rails console上で `ExecJS.runtime.name` で確認)

Comment: コンソール上で何と入力すればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: ExecJS.runtime.nameと入力しても入力可能なコマンドとして認識されていませんとでてしまいます。

Comment: rails console上ですよ。

Comment: 同じエラーが出ました。上記方法で確認したら"JScript"と出ました。